# how do i add extra text fields "flutter_login: ^5.0.0" in flutter

Tags: flutter, authentication

I'd like to incorporate the "`flutter_login: ^5.0.0`" package into my code, which currently provides only default email and password fields. How can I include additional text fields in the login form?

**this is what i have tried doing. **

```
      logo: const AssetImage('assets/xxxxxx.png'),
      onLogin: _authUser,
      theme: LoginTheme(
        primaryColor: const Color(0xFFe69597)
      ),
      onSignup: _signupUser,
      onSubmitAnimationCompleted: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => Home(),
        ));
      },
      onRecoverPassword: _recoverPassword,
    );
```

Comment: To incorporate additional text fields into your login form using the "flutter_login: ^5.0.0" package, you can use the additionalSignUpFields option. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_login#installation - this option allows you to add up to 6 additional fields. However, these fields will only appear during the sign-up process, not during login. If you require additional fields during login, unfortunately, this package does not currently support that. There is an open issue regarding this on GitHub (https://github.com/NearHuscarl/flutter_login/issues/434), but it has not yet been addressed.

Comment: I tried, but I cannot see them.